# How to create a button adding a new option to wordpress admin menu?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm writing my own theme and I want it to be possible to add links to social network accounts in the settings menu. The number of links can be any. In the admin panel on the settings page there should be a button “add social network”, when clicked, two new fields appear: an icon and a link. I figured out how to add new options to the admin panel through the theme's functions.php, but I want the user to be able to add a new option directly in the admin panel. How can I do that?